# Writing quotes of a business name with star as hyphen

Tags: word-choice, names

I have a business with a name e.g. "my business".

Wherever you see the company name it's always written as **my★business** - the company logo is similar and anywhere we write the name on the website that's how it looks.

My question is: Is there a wrong way to write this when quoting someone who has mentioned the business? For example, on our site we have a quotes section, a collection of quotes from users which we publish. One of them might be:

"I started using **my★business** after a friend told me about their website"

Is that the correct way to write the company name or should it be "my business" without the star? Or doesn't it matter?

Not sure how to tag this so apologies if incorrect.

Comment: This is a question of design. Personally, I would never use special characters in copy, quotes, or in any case where it's embedded in text. I would opt instead for the legal name, which won't

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to write the company name is to write the company name.

The correct way to write the company name is not to try to recreate the company logo in ASCII art, or Unicode art, or whatever strikes your fancy.

You write:

> I went to Walmart and bought a bottle of Coca-Cola.

You do not write:

> I went to WAL★MART and bought a bottle of [image].

Of course you are free to try and pull off that stunt on the company's own website, but you can't expect normal people to follow suit elsewhere, and indeed you must expect them not to.

Comment: +1 Also, you will find that almost all major companies register a trademark that consists of a word mark (all block caps, only standard punctuation), even when they also have a preferred design mark (including images or logos) or stylized writing (using a special font or cursive style). The mark including a star would be considered a design mark.

Comment: There are gray areas, however, that can be easily reproduced. For example, what if a company puts and ! at the end of its name, or displays its name in all lowercase.